# casting convertible types in coq

Tags: types, casting, coq

In the following:

```
Lemma test:
  forall n j  (jn : j < n)  (ln : j + 0 < n) (P:  forall {x} {y}, (x<y) -> nat),
    P ln = P jn.
```

Types *ln* an *jn* seems to be convertible to each other (from arithmetics point of view). How can I use that fact to prove the lemma above? I can easily prove `assert(JL: j < n -> j + 0 < n) by auto.` but I fail to see how to apply this to **types**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The types are *not* convertible to each other, because of the way addition on the natural numbers is defined in Coq (i.e., by recursion on the first argument). As a matter of fact, the only reason your lemma can be typed in Coq at all is that the first implicit argument of `P` is instantiated to `j + 0` on the right-hand side.

Unfortunately, even if these types *were* convertible, it would not be possible to prove this lemma without additional assumptions, because it requires the axiom of *propositional extensionality* (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26572089/how-or-is-that-possible-to-prove-or-falsify-forall-p-q-prop-p-q-q/26574599#26574599), for instance).

Comment: thanks. I understand it is not provable in general, but I was able to prove it for particular P.

Comment: I am sorry, but I still do not understand. Even if I make 'x' and 'y' non-implicit, 'P' takes natural number so 'j' and 'j+0' are of type 'nat' and I can prove they are equivalent. From common sense, from proof 'j+0<n' I can prove 'j<n', so I do not see why my lemma should not be provable in principle. Can you provide some additional explanation?

Comment: Aren't all proofs of "m < n" provably equal?

Comment: Yes, that's actually true: proofs of "m < n" _are_ proof irrelevant... I should edit this.

Answer (score 2):

The lemma is not provable.  Try `intros. remember (j+0) as Q. rewrite <- plus_n_O in HeqQ. subst Q.`  It will get rid of the `+ 0`.  Your goal is now

```
P j n ln = P j n jn
```

Both sides are of type `nat`.  But now you need to prove that these two `nat`s are equal, without knowing anything else about them...

EDIT:

Actually I was a little too quick... The value of the function `P` cannot depend on `ln` and `jn` since they are `Prop`s, .  But to prove that, you need [*proof irrelevance*](https://coq.inria.fr/faq#htoc40).

If you do `Require Import ProofIrrelevance.` you get the axiom

```
Axiom proof_irrelevance : forall (P:Prop) (p1 p2:P), p1 = p2.
```

It is not a consequence of Coq's logic, but it is consistent with it (and often is just what we mean with a proof - two formally correct arguments are equally true even if they differ in the details).

Now you just do

```
rewrite (proof_irrelevance _ ln jn). reflexivity. Qed.
```

Comment: I added some comments about using *proof irrelevance* to finish the proof.