# How to prove (n = n) = (m = m) in Coq?

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

I am confused about the evidence and `Prop` etc. in Coq. How do we prove that `(n = n) = (m = m)`?

My intention is to show this is somehow `True=True`. But this is even correct formulation?

What I tried so far is:

```
Theorem test: forall m n:nat, (n = n) = (m = m).
Proof. intros. simpl.
```

But `simpl.` does nothing, and `reflexivity` neither. This is just an example, in general, I need to prove this for any type `X` if possible.

Comment: Have you considered to prove: `(n = n) <-> (m = m)`? Since `<->` can be seen as equality between propositions, in Coq.

Comment: @RodrigoRibeiro Thanks for the pointer. I'll try that. The example I showed is extracted from a larger proof. But I may have posed the assertion wrong.

Comment: Interesting question! I think this should fail because it need not be that `n = m` and so `refl n <> refl m`. I've spent the last hour trying to prove that `(a=a)=(b=b)` fails if `a<>b` but am still stuck. I've tried some interesting approaches and might post an "answer" later on detailing why the stuff I tried must fail. (But right now I just have a headache…)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`n = n` and `m = m` are both *propsitions*, so they're of sort `Prop` rather than sort `Set`. This basically means that `n = n` is like a statement (that has to be proved) rather than something like `true : boolean`.

Instead, you could try proving something like: `n-n = m-m`, or, you could define a function `nat_equal : nat -> bool` that, given a natural, mapped it to bool, and then prove `nat_equal n = nat_equal m`.

If you really want to assert that the *statements* are equal, you'll need propositional extensionality.

Answer (score 1):

It is *not* possible to prove what you are asking for without assuming additional axioms; cf. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26572089/how-or-is-that-possible-to-prove-or-falsify-forall-p-q-prop-p-q-q/26574599#26574599).